# Click on thumbnail > view next thumbnail (loop)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to both jquery and javascript and try to learn. I have a site that displays many different thumbnails and now I want the thumbnails to be clickable to view next thumbnail, and when there is no more thumbnails associated to the element the first thumbnail will show again (loops).

I also preferably want the thumbnails to load onclick and not all at the same time the visitor enter the page (becuse then it can be alot of thumbnails associated to all elements to load at once).

So basically I want to change the img src and load next thumbnail when visitor clicks on a thumbnail, I dont know how to write this code correcly.

Sorry for some incorrect english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to use existing complete solution.

Try to search 'image slider'.

http://www.google.com/search?q=image%20slider